# How do I save a document through google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the code. I can't debug since it uses the trigger when the respondent submits the form.

```
    // This code opens the doc and names it what you wanted it named above. It also appends any other language to the title that you wish.  My sample below will title each document as docName + 'for' + Lname or (OA Graduate Assistant Application for Last Name of user).
    var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName+' for '+ Lname)
    .getId();

    // Open the temporary document
    var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

    // Get the document’s body section
    var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

    //code that makes edits
    copyBody.replaceText('keyTimestamp', Timestamp);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyPemail', Pemail);

//define the source folder to save the file in
    var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);

//add this file to the source folder
    dir.addFile(copyDoc);


    copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```

There is no file stored in the specified folder and in my entire google drive. What's the problem? All the variables are defined correctly (I just omitted the var statements).

Comment: Is the value being passed to [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid), a valid Drive File ID?

Comment: Yes the file is valid

Comment: Is there a way I can debug this problem

Comment: If nothing's happening, then maybe you're not using the right commands. Saving a file to Google Drive using Apps Script is indicated here [Uploading files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

Answer (score 0):

How about following script?

"addFile()" is a method of Class DriveApp. So the file has to be retrieved by the method of DriveApp. For your script, it used "getFileById()".

```
// This code opens the doc and names it what you wanted it named above. It also appends any other language to the title that you wish.  My sample below will title each document as docName + 'for' + Lname or (OA Graduate Assistant Application for Last Name of user).
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+ Lname)
.getId();

// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

//code that makes edits
copyBody.replaceText('keyTimestamp', Timestamp);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPemail', Pemail);

//define the source folder to save the file in
var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);

//add this file to the source folder
dir.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(copyId));


copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```

If this is no solution, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

DriveApp.addFile() is a deprecated method, instead you should the folder when the file is created.

```
// Folder and id
var idFolder = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvyxz";
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idFolder);
var idDoc = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvyxz";
var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(idDoc);  
// Create a copy of the doc and then especify the folder in which it is gonna be stored
var docCopy = doc.makeCopy(file_name,folder);
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```